# Logging into Facebook with test account using Selenium

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have some PHP code that creates a Facebook test account in my application using the graph api. I've tested this code out, and it works fine.

I'm having trouble actually logging into Facebook as the test user using [Selenium Webdriver (for PHP)](http://code.google.com/p/php-webdriver-bindings/).

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
class FB_OAuthTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
    private $fbUtils = null;
    private $fbUser = null;
    private $startUrl = 'http://my.start.page';

    protected function setUp() {
        $this->webdriver = new WebDriver(Config::SELENIUM_SERVER, Config::SELENIUM_PORT);
        $this->webdriver->connect(Config::BROWSER);

        $this->fbUtils = new FBUtils(Config::FB_APP_ID, Config::FB_APP_SECRET);

        // create new FB test user here
        $this->fbUser = $this->fbUtils->createNewTestUser();
    }

    protected function tearDown() {
        // delete the test user when we're done
        if($this->fbUser != null) {
            $this->fbUtils->deleteTestUser($this->fbUser->id);
        }
        $this->webdriver->close();
    }

    // the magic happens here
    public function testOAuth() {    
        // "login" as test user by requesting the login url that they give
        $this->webdriver->get($this->fbUser->login_url);

        // start the app workflow: go to a page with a FB OAuth button
        $this->webdriver->get($this->startUrl); 
        $this->assertTrue(isTextPresent("FB_OAuth_Test_Start", $this->webdriver));

        // click the button to begin the FB OAuth process
        $oAuthButton = $this->webdriver->findElementBy(LocatorStrategy::xpath, "//button[@control='FBLogin1']");
        $oAuthButton->click();

        // The Facebook login/OAuth dialog shows up now, and forces me to login
        // despite first going to the FB user's login url

        // sleep for the hell of it, just to make sure the FB login dialog loads
        sleep(5);

        // Selenium fails here - not finding the input with id='email', despite it existing on the page
        $emailField = $this->webdriver->findElementBy(LocatorStrategy::xpath, "//input[id='email']");
        if ($emailField) {
            $emailField->sendKeys(array($this->fbUser->email));
            $emailField->submit();
        } else {
            $this->fail('FB login email field not found');
        }

        $passwordField = $this->webdriver->findElementBy(LocatorStrategy::xpath, "//input[id='pass']");
        if ($passwordField) {
            $passwordField->sendKeys(array($this->fbUser->password));
            $passwordField->submit();
        } else {
            $this->fail('FB login password field not found');
        }

        $loginButton = $this->webdriver->findElementBy(LocatorStrategy::xpath, "//input[name='login']");
        if ($loginButton) {
            $loginButton->click();
        } else {
            $this->fail('FB login button not found');
        }

        $grantAppPermission = $this->webdriver->findElementBy(LocatorStrategy::name, "grant_clicked");
        $grantAppPermission->click();

        $this->assertTrue(isTextPresent("FB_OAuth_Test_Success", $this->webdriver));
    }
}
```

As you can see from the code comments, Selenium can't find the 'email' input element, and the test fails. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

**Update**

I've even tried doing something fairly direct, like the code blow, and it still doesn't work.

```
private function loginToFacebook() {
    $this->webdriver->get('https://www.facebook.com/login.php?login_attempt=1');

    sleep(1);

    $emailField = $this->webdriver->findElementBy(LocatorStrategy::xpath, "//input[id='email']");
    if ($emailField) {
        $emailField->sendKeys(array($this->fbUser->email));
        $emailField->submit();
    } else {
        $this->fail('FB login email field not found');
    }

    $passwordField = $this->webdriver->findElementBy(LocatorStrategy::xpath, "//input[id='pass']");
    if ($passwordField) {
        $passwordField->sendKeys(array($this->fbUser->password));
        $passwordField->submit();
    } else {
        $this->fail('FB login password field not found');
    }

    $loginButton = $this->webdriver->findElementBy(LocatorStrategy::xpath, "//input[name='login']");
    if ($loginButton) {
        $loginButton->click();
    } else {
        $this->fail('FB login button not found');
    }
}
```

**Update: Here's the Working Code**

```
private function loginToFacebook() {
    $this->webdriver->get('https://www.facebook.com/login.php?login_attempt=1');

    $emailField = $this->webdriver->findElementBy(LocatorStrategy::id, 'email');
    if ($emailField) {
        $emailField->sendKeys(array($this->fbUser->email));
    } else {
        $this->fail('FB login email field not found');
    }

    $passwordField = $this->webdriver->findElementBy(LocatorStrategy::id, 'pass');
    if ($passwordField) {
        $passwordField->sendKeys(array($this->fbUser->password));
    } else {
        $this->fail('FB login password field not found');
    }

    $loginButton = $this->webdriver->findElementBy(LocatorStrategy::xpath, "//input[@name='login']");
    if ($loginButton) {
        $loginButton->click();
    } else {
        $this->fail('FB login button not found');
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the facebook login page open up as a popup?

Comment: I set up OAuth so it doesn't open as a popup, and instead opens on the same page. Additionally, the Facebook login page shows up just fine if I use the loginToFacebook() method towards the bottom.

Comment: o i got ur mistake, posting my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have defined ur xpath expression incorrectly

it should have been `//input[@id='email'] ##Note the @ sign (not sure you need to escape '@' with a blackslash)`

But none the less try changing how you try to locate your web elements

```
 // try locating by LocatorStrategy id
        $emailField = $this->webdriver->findElementBy(LocatorStrategy::id, 'email');
        if ($emailField) {
            $emailField->sendKeys(array($this->fbUser->email));
            $emailField->submit();
        } else {
            $this->fail('FB login email field not found');
        }
```

It is quicker to search by `id`, `name` as compared to `xpath`.

make the same changes for password field as well, like so

`$passwordField = $this->webdriver->findElementBy(LocatorStrategy::id, "pass");`

Comment: D'oh. I can't believe I missed that, thank you! I'll try it out when I get back to work tomorrow and give it a shot. Unfortunately Facebook.com doesn't have the @id atrribute on input fields, so I have to do it using this xpath strategy. Slow is a-OK with me for these tests, since they're browser tests they won't get run very often.

Comment: That worked, thanks! I was also doing some dumb stuff like calling `submit()` right after sending stuff to the password field.

Comment: Great that it worked. I am also pretty sure you will be able to locate your element based on `id`. Anyways All the best.